# Benefits of extra DNS config for Google Cloud Private Google Access

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, nat, google-compute-engine

Setup:

- VM running in a subnet with public NAT enabled.
- VM has only internal IP address.
- VM needs to connect to Google APIs and services without traversing public internet.

Enabling NAT automatically enables PGA as per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/nat-product-interactions#interaction-pga). PGA will be used to access Google APIs and services. Traffic to Google APIs and services will not pass through NAT to the public internet. This can be confirmed by enabling Cloud NAT logs, which will fail to include entries related to such traffic.

In such case what are the benefits or use cases for additional [DNS configuration](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#config-domain) for `private.googleapis.com`, other than the opportunity for more fine-grained network traffic monitoring or the ability to define more strict egress firewall rules?